# Skyrim House Keeping/Downloading Hearthfire

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-hearthfire

I have purchased 2 different houses in the base Skyrim Elder Scrolls 5 Game. I want to download Hearthfire, but I am afraid of losing all of my stuff because I shoved a lot of stuff in there. Here is the question I am really asking.

If I download Hearthfire, will I lose my stuff?

Answer (score 4):

Don't worry, your loot will be safe.

Hearthfire's new houses aren't actually in place of any of the houses that were there in vanilla Skyrim - instead, three areas of the countryside are converted into potential building sites for Homesteads.

Your purchased houses and their contents, therefore, won't be altered.

Answer (score -2):

You won't loose all of your loot even if you want to have Hearthfire. :)

Comment: Where did you learn this information? Could you provide a source?